# Query is correct but give me sqlexception in java

Tags: mysql, jdbc, syntax-error, access-violation, sqlexception

JDBC executeUpdate() executes this MySqlQuery:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TaskLog 
(TaskID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
NoOfLock int NOT NULL,
LastAcquired varchar(50) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(TaskID))
```

It gives me this:

```
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY(TaskID))' at line 1
```

I tried executing it in PhpMyAdmin, it works! So I don't understand why it doesn't work when executing through java codes

Comment: I think he said 'java codes'. You has codes. Can we has codes?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax can be different from one DBMS to another. It might work in MySQl, but the following one should work on most systems:

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TaskLog 
(TaskID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
NoOfLock int NOT NULL,
LastAcquired varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_TaskID PRIMARY KEY(TaskID))
```